# How to force redirect control to a new page in in case of ajax response in hybris?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

Consider a scenario, I have wrote one ajax call which will call my controller method. According to condition, two responses possible for return as follows:

1. in case of success, return response
2. in case of failure, will redirect to other page

Expected,
It should redirect to specified page in case of failure

Current Working condition,
It is redirecting to other page controller, generating html page data in form of string and returning to ajax response. But it is not getting redirected to specified page!

How can we cancel the ajax which is expecting response in return and force to redirect to specified page?

Comment: If you can send the control to a controller, a simple solution can be to create a controller, send the control to this controller, and redirect to the desired page from this controller.

Comment: Sending control to new controller is possible. But, only thing is, ajax will be in progress! Wherever control will flow at the end it has to return a response to ajax and ajax not redirecting to new returned html!!

Comment: You will have to write a method which has url mapping for the url you redirect and return a page from there.

Comment: I am getting page in form of html, but it is getting returned to response of ajax which is not getting redirected